# Regex rule stop capturing when specific word is find

Tags: regex, pcre2

I'm working with regex on PRCE2 environment.

When I perform a capture group, I know perfectly how to stop when I find a specific character. For example: if I have following log portion:

```
logger=CGP  spid=5116
```

I know I can capture the logger value and save it as "logger" with:

```
logger\=(?<logger>[^\s]+)
```

That means: start capture after `=` and stop when you ecounter a space.
But what about if I want order: stop when a specific **word** is met?

For example, if I have:

```
msg=Reject access   logger=CGP
```

If I want capture `msg` field value, I cannot use a space as stop character: first space must be included. I must stop when `logger` word is encountered.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use it like this with a following lookahead:

```bash
\bmsg=(?<logger>.+?)(?=\h+logger=)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2e6zVd/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\bmsg`: Match word `msg`
- `=`: Match `=`
- `(?<logger>.+?)`: Capture group `logger` that match 1+ of any character (lazy match)
- `(?=\h+logger=)`: Lookahead to assert that we have 1+ whitespaces followed by `logger=` text ahead of the current position

Comment: msg\=(.*)(logger=).*  is simpler

Comment: Text `logger` may come later in the same line besides trailing spaces need to be taken care of

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, `msg\=(.*)(logger=).*` pattern will OK. you should get first capturing group

Comment: Hi there, you don't need the escape before `\=` and you could omit the trailing `.*` as the `(.*)` before makes sure that you already match the last occurrence.